# move third y-axis to right

Tags: python, matplotlib, multiple-axes

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.75)

twin1 = ax.twinx()
twin2 = ax.twinx()

#twin2.spines.right.set_position(("axes", 1.2))

p1, = ax.plot([0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], "b-", label="Density")
p2, = twin1.plot([0, 1, 2], [0, 3, 2], "r-", label="Temperature")
p3, = twin2.plot([0, 1, 2], [50, 30, 15], "g-", label="Velocity")

ax.set_xlim(0, 2)
ax.set_ylim(0, 2)
twin1.set_ylim(0, 4)
twin2.set_ylim(1, 65)

ax.set_xlabel("Distance")
ax.set_ylabel("Density")
twin1.set_ylabel("Temperature")
twin2.set_ylabel("Velocity")

ax.yaxis.label.set_color(p1.get_color())
twin1.yaxis.label.set_color(p2.get_color())
twin2.yaxis.label.set_color(p3.get_color())

tkw = dict(size=4, width=1.5)
ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors=p1.get_color(), **tkw)
twin1.tick_params(axis='y', colors=p2.get_color(), **tkw)
twin2.tick_params(axis='y', colors=p3.get_color(), **tkw)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', **tkw)

ax.legend(handles=[p1, p2, p3])

plt.show()
```

I'd like to move 'temperature axis' (twin2) to the right. I tried

```
twin2.spines.right.set_position(("axes", 1.2))
```

but it isn't working and sending an error ([image: error]).

and I don't want it overlaping ([image: overlap])

Source: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks_and_spines/multiple_yaxis_with_spines.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

EDIT: It isn't a bug apparently - it's [a feature added in version 3.4.0](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/20230)

---

This might be a bug - as it only happens when trying to run `twin2.spines.right.set_position(("axes", 1.2))` on the `ipython` terminal and not if you call it from a script. Perhaps the ordered dictionary values are not being correctly set as attributes, as they seems to be present:

```py
>> twin2.spines
OrderedDict([('left', <matplotlib.spines.Spine at 0x7fc4f006a280>),
             ('right', <matplotlib.spines.Spine at 0x7fc4f006a370>),
             ('bottom', <matplotlib.spines.Spine at 0x7fc4f006a460>),
             ('top', <matplotlib.spines.Spine at 0x7fc4f006a550>)])
```

You can work around this by manually getting the spine from the dictionary like this:

```py
twin2.spines['right'].set_position(("axes", 1.2))
```

By the way, you need to call `set_position` on `twin1` if you want temperature shifted. `twin2` will shift the velocity axis.

[image: plot]